# Add check constraint for a column in child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

Account:

```
ID (NUMBER), type_of_acc (VARCHAR), (only values ADMIN or USER);
```

BAN:

```
ID_A(NUMBER), ID_U(NUMBER);
```

both `ID_A` and `ID_U` are foreign keys referencing `ID` from table `Account`.

I need to add a constraint that checks ID_A has only values ID

```
WHERE type_of_acc = 'ADMIN'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2913), you cannot do that which `CHECK`s constraints for several reasons, in your use case, specially because:

> The condition of a check constraint can refer to any column in the table, but it cannot refer to columns of other tables.

And:

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:
>
> - Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
> - Calls to user-defined functions

In order to achieve that functionally, probably the way to go will be to create a trigger for your `BAN` table. Consider for instance:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_ban_boiu
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON BAN  
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_aux NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.id_a IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_aux
      FROM account
     WHERE id = :NEW.id_a
       AND type_of_acc = 'ADMIN';

    IF v_aux = 0 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Invalid value for ID_A');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```